# TypeScript - type cast not returning falsey value as expected

Tags: typescript, casting, ts-node

I would like the casting of a string at runtime to return a falsey value if the type is mismatched. Namely, when I run the following with `ts-node@10.7.0`, I encounter unexpected results:

```js
$ ts-node
> 0 as 'B' | 'C' | 'D' || 'foo'         // ✅ throws precompiler error as expected
--------------
> '' as 'B' | 'C' | 'D' || 'foo'        // ✅ prints 'foo' as expected
'foo' 
> undefined as 'B' | 'C' | 'D' || 'foo' // ✅ prints 'foo' as expected
'foo' 
> null as 'B' | 'C' | 'D' || 'foo'      // ✅ prints 'foo' as expected
'foo' 
> 'B' as 'B' | 'C' | 'D' || 'foo'       // ✅ prints 'B' as expected
'B' 
> 'A' as 'B' | 'C' | 'D' || 'foo'       // ❌ prints 'A' instead of 'foo' <-- UNEXPECTED
'A'
```

I clearly misunderstand how casting works, but how do I implement the logic I am trying to achieve where I expected `'A' as 'B' | 'C' | 'D'` to return a falsey value?

Comment: `||` is a runtime operator while `as 'B' | 'C' | 'D'` only has effect during compile time. You should not expect different behaviour at runtime when you use type assertions

Comment: @TobiasS. thanks! that makes a lot of sense now that you explain that

Comment: @NoodleOfDeath: I would not recommend ever using `||` like that. Relying on conversion to falsy can easily lead to bugs.

Comment: @H.B. How does using `possiblyFalseyVariable || 'other'` differ from `possiblyFalseyVariable ? possiblyFalseyVariable : 'other'`? I assumed they have the same behavior and I see the latter being used in production and tutorials everywhere

Comment: @NoodleOfDeath: They should have the same behavior, the problem is that the behavior of the conversion to boolean is fairly complex and in some cases not particularly intuitive. So you might end up with a value that would be valid but is rejected because the algorithm just turns it into `false`.

Comment: @H.B. Got it. So as long as you're 100% confident the truth maps of those operators on your falsey variables have no edge cases you didn't think of, it's an acceptable thing to use?

Comment: @NoodleOfDeath Yes, I suppose. Most functions don't have to accept arbitrary values, so there will not be that many cases to consider, but at the same time, if there are not many cases, you might as well check them explicitly. E.g. if a value is `number | null | undefined` and I want to check if this is "set", I would just check `value != null`, that way I cannot run into the issue of `0` being rejected because it would be converted to `false`. Using `typeof` can also be very helpful to do an initial narrowing.

Answer (score 2):

`as` is a type assertion, it does not have a runtime effect. You need to do some manual checking of the value instead. Something like:

```
const allowed = new Set(['B', 'C', 'D']);
const input: string = 'A';
const value = allowed.has(input) ? input : 'foo';
```

You then can assert that value is `'B' | 'C' | 'D' | 'foo'` using `as`.

[Playground (runnable)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQGoEMA2JUAUMYADiFAFyJZgCeAlIgN4BQiiECAzlNTjnADuqACaIAvIjCpBiAMroCAbQDkAIRUAaRCoDCWnQBEVAXXoBuNh268ATqi4gcvSbgHCRAOgAWWLkVJyRgB%20RGIyXioVYDg4FUsreygQWyR7R2dqLh0NRAAfHX18oxVi6Nj4lgBfFhZOMC44HFRPAWQCNExcfAIABnoLOu4mlraO9Gw8QhUVAct6xubWuHbOyZ7wEVRgYlE5oYaR5dWJ7sIwJxx9haOxtbOCdVnBm6W706nHgEFnyyA)
[Playground using type-fu to not repeat literals](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQGoEMA2JUAUMYADiFAFyJZgCeAlIgN4BQiiECAzlNTjnADuqACaIAvIjCpBiAMroCAbQDkAIRUAaRCoDCWnQBEVAXWpcO3KPQDcbS2B6JguHACMsEANYSdwOHAqduycjrwATqhcIDi8kq5CogB0ABZYXESk5IwA-IjEZLxULvwe3nb2kVAg4UiR0bHm8ujYeFEAPFC0JKhwwHwCwiIAfIgAPohdPX3OrmVedgC%20LCxTqM2YuPhc7QAqo5K7iKgAHlCoYCIWClDtxMCo4YgAqqN5z4hU0gBujxWhXDgOFQSQEyAIaE2bQIAAZ6LYWACgSCwRCWltCCoVPC7EjgaC4ODIa18ARwCJUMBiKIcYjuMiCUT0dCwDEcLS8SjCWioaT1NiEZzGTySZiAIICuxAA)

Comment: All that just to get a runtime behavior that implements the type assertion? I'm surprised there is nothing built in for this; runtime falsey typecasting isn't anything new...

Comment: You can convert to various types using their constructors, but this is pretty specific and to my knowledge there are not many languages that can just cast and coerce a string to a subset of literals. There are a lot of validation libraries that can help implement checks of varying complexity. Personally I quite like [Zod](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod) for validating requests on the server.

Answer (score 1):

The "cleanest" way to work with unknown literals in my opinion is using a type guard.

```
type YourLiteralType = 'B' | 'C' | 'D'

// Important part is the return type, and returning a boolean value
function isYourLiteralType(input: unknown): input is YourLiteralType {
  return input === 'B' || input === 'C' || input === 'D'
}

const a = 'A'

// Works with ifs
if (isYourLiteralType(a)) {
  // a is "casted" to YourLiteralType
}


function doSomethingWithYourLiteralType(input: YourLiteralType) {
  // Raises a compiler error if not called with the appropriate type
}

// Also works with ternaries
const x = isYourLiteralType(a) ? doSomethingWithYourLiteralType(a) : undefined
```

Comment: This is a great answer and seems like really good design. It's odd I don't see a lot of production code employing this design